# Ansible Multiline prompt string ios_command module

Tags: ios, ansible

I'm trying to reload a device with ansible ios_command.

The manual reload output is :

router#reload

Reload command is being issued on Active unit, this will reload the whole stack

Proceed with reload? [confirm]

My reload playbook section looks like :

```
commands:
  -command: reload
    prompt: 'Proceed with reload? [confirm]'
    answer: "\r"
```

But I can not get it working. How can I specify several lines for prompt parsing?

Answer (score 2):

Based on akhil01 answer, this worked for me

```
name: Confirmation Required
    pause:
      prompt: |
        proceed with reload ?

        {{ vars_also_works }}

        Press ENTER to continue or CTRL+C and A to abort...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `with_items`, this worked for me.

```
name: Confirmation Required
    pause:
      prompt: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: |
      proceed with reload ?
      Press ENTER to continue or CTRL+C and A to abort...
```